# VBA Userform set Controls as Private instead of Public

Tags: vba, private, public, userform

Summary:
In a vba Userform, is there a way to set the elements on the form to Private instead of Public?

Why:
My userform is a general progress bar that could be used by other programmers in the same VBAProject.
I don't want them to access the elements directly for setting information text.

Example for label lblInformation:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim MyProgressBar As New frmProgressBar
    MyProgressBar.Show vbModeless
```

What I to force them to use:

```
    MyProgressBar.setInformation = "Running ..."
```

What I want to avoid:

```
    MyProgressBar.lblInformation.Caption = "Running ..."
```

How can I set lblInformation to Private instead of Public?

(rest of the code)

```
    Unload ProgressBar
End Sub
```

Application (which does not matter):
VBA7 in Autodesk Inventor 2014

Comment: create a wrapper for the standard userform. your own class with private properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read (in Professional Excel Development by Bovey, et. al., as well as in other sources), the standard VBA solution for this is to 1) Use a Class Module to define an interface, which lists the functions (properties, subs, etc.) you want to expose. 2) In your Form Module, put an "Implements" statement and then add code that will be accessed by the public routines declared in the interface. 3) Then, in your application, use the interface rather than the form itself.

So in a class module called, let's say, iProgressBar, list what you want to be publicly avaiable:

```
Public Property Let Information(ByVal sNew As String)
End Property

Public Property Get Information() As String
End Property

Public Sub UpdateProgress(ByVal dNew As Double)
End Sub

'etc...
```

That is your interface. Then at the top of your frmProgressBar module, put

```
Implements iProgressBar
```

Once you have that statement, look at the dropdowns at the top of the code window. Choose iProgressBar from the left dropdown. Then, choose one of its public elements from the right dropdown and a code block (like below) will be inserted. In this block, you specify what each public element of your progress bar does.

```
Private Property Let iProgressBar_Information(ByVal str As String)

    Me.lblInformation.Caption = str 

    'Refresh the form
    Me.Repaint

End Property

Private Sub iProgressBar_UpdateProgress(ByVal dNew As Double)

    'Code to update progress on the form

End Property
```

Then when you want a progress bar in your application, **declare your variable as the class interface** but ***assign an instance of the form*** to that variable.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim MyProgressBar As iProgressBar
    Set MyProgressBar = New frmProgressBar

    'More code

    'This will work MyProgressBar was dim'ed as iProgressBar, which has an Information property
    MyProgressBar.Information = "Running ..."

    'This will not work because iProgressBar has no lbl...
    MyProgressBar.lblInformation.Caption = "Running ..."

    'More code
End Sub
```

The only limitation here is that someone can still come along into your project and start using the form directly, instead of the interface. I don't think there's any simple VBA-only way to force people to do what you want here. This is just a VBA "best practice" to help ease collaboration and avoid errors. (It's probably simple to force the behavior you want if you compile a library, but that takes you outside of VBA).

EDIT:

Actually, I think there is another step you can take toward forcing the behavior you want. You can probably use a TypeOf... Is... expression to prevent the form from opening on its own. Within the UserForm_Initialize routine, put some version of the following:

```
If Not TypeOf Me Is iProgressBar Then

    'Clever code that will cause initialization to fail.

End If
```

Comment: Especially the initialization catch I like the most :)